Entuity (monitoring SW) databse backup
If anyone is using quite obscure monitoring system named Entuity, I'm trying to find a good way of extending its database.
Currently the system is using MySQL database. For some reason its setup to retain only 3 weeks of stream data (alarms) before deleting them. I'm trying to find most logical way of extending this database, and potentially move this data to secondary MySQL DB on another server.
Entuity documentation is of no help. I'm looking into potentially:
MySQL Replication with Selective Load Balancing
DB Partitioning / Sharding
Archiving and Data Purging

Its a live and critical system and currently proposed approach is to export CSV reports of needed data (alarms) and retain them on disk, or import to another DB, which i dont believe is correct solution.

I would expect retention to be an application setting and something that is typically set to ensure that data is not kept longer than needed or doesn't consume more space than desired and adjusting that in the application should usually be the easiest. https://support.entuity.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020269658-Polled-data-retention-in-Entuity - Interestingly it seems that that documentation also has an option to schedule direct data exports to another database for archiving https://support.entuity.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002994513-How-do-I-export-Entuity-data-to-a-separate-database#export

AFAIK archiving to another database is quite normal and common when your typical usage requirements only need  current data and old events are only queried for reporting and not day-to-day operations.

Thank you - the target database setting is something i read trough but it does not seem to work as i would expect, as it has very specific settings of Data Sets involved.
The retention is set for shorter-than-needed time because of resources issues. This is why extended database (or exporting CSV reports) is now discussed.
I'm looking fore more elegant way than that, but i'm not in position to question current settings, hence focus on second databse.
